# xDebug profiler completely ignores sources behind Phalcon native code

Tags: xdebug, phalcon, xdebug-profiler

My xDebug v2.2.3 for PHP 5.5 completely ignores souce code behind Phalcon native code, like controllers, models, views. Only bootstrap file and method called from there are available.

Here is my xDebug configuration in php.ini:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 0
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
```

Answer (score 2):

you should install **Xdebug 2.2.6**.
it is fixed now, and works like magic

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who is still having this problem from within PHPStorm using a remote interpreter you should try two things:

- Get a copy of the phalcon dev-tools and as the ide/ folder as an External Library from the project window. I don't know if this changes anything but I already had this done when I found the fix (in the next point) so I don't know if it's required.
- Set up path mappings for each top level directory in your project (including vendor/) to the directory in your remote server. I think it breaks when it skips into the Phalcon code but it seems if you specify each path mapping it'll reconnect once it re-enters your project scope.